# Call gsm modem service from PHP code

Tags: php, service, sms, daemon, gsm

I am creating queue management system at work and neeed to implement gsm modem to send sms confirmation to users.

I have used PHP DIO library for accessing COM port and usedAT commands to send SMS.

But I want to keep separate my AT commands as another process, not associated with httpd.exe. Is it possible to use some gsm modem service, probably written in some other language, separately and call it from php code?

Is it possible to add PHP script to listen to some socket, and add Python script to this socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this behavior, implementing what's so called: inter-process communications. I created Python socket server always listening for socket. In my PHP code, I have written function to pass data to socket(function, script name and params). So when I need to use Gsm, I sent all info to socket from PHP. Python socket server gets this info and calls Python script, to handle AT commands.